# Are there regulations for water skiing in a ASEL aircraft?

Tags: faa-regulations, bush-flying

What are the regulations regarding water skiing with ASEL aircraft, as in touching your tires down in a particular body of water such as a lake or river? Sometimes referred to hydroplaning.

Comment: Do you mean a) skimming the surface of the water with the aircraft's tires, or b) towing a water skier behind the aircraft?

Comment: Choosing between the two sounds like settling.

Comment: @Pondlife I can’t quite see how you would initiate b) - catch bungee type rope? exit flying aircraft with water skis attached? It would at least be conceivable with a float plane, but on a land plane... interesting!

Comment: Water skiing, water skimming and hydroplaning are all terms used to describe the intended activity.

Comment: @CptReynolds I don't know either, but I would bet a lot of fake internet money that someone somewhere has found a way!

Comment: @Pondlife Indeed! The trick is to transfer from a 60mph speedboat to a 80mph C152: https://youtu.be/XF7SnJCaanU

Comment: @CptReynolds look up the bucket drop maneuver. Bet you could use it to slowly transfer speed to a waterskier.

Answer (score 4):

[image]
([bush-air.com](http://www.bush-air.com/Bush_and_mountain_flying_3rd_edition_revised_web_intro.pdf))

I couldn't find any regulations for it. But the closest thing to an official mention of it I found was in a 2009 piece on [Anchorage Daily News](https://www.adn.com/alaska-news/article/river-skimming-stunt-draws-attention-unlicensed-pilot/2009/05/01/), where an unlicensed pilot water skied, hit a sandbar, and it didn't end nicely for his Super Cub.

The FAA regional counsel said:

> The practice is called water-skiing, and it is not encouraged. It was developed for landing in tight quarters, like sand bars where space is short, but doing it wrong can be disastrous.

Answer (score 1):

No regs against it but is strongly discouraged. If an accident did occur, you’re likely to be cited under [14 CFR 91.13](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.13) Careless and Reckless Operation and the incident will probably be used as evidence in a Wrongful Injury/Death lawsuit.

Answer (score 0):

No "hydroplaning" with tires or "skimming" with skis is not illegal.

It's very common in Alaska and was supposedly started (~1930-1935) by bush pilot ["Bob Reeves" delivering freight with skis](http://youtube.com/watch?v=zpK6Q_sdJMw) from Valdez Alaska mud flats to higher snow covered altitudes and glaciers. It's now common among J3 Cubs with balloon tires (often Goodyear Blimp tires).
[image]
[Youtube clip of Bob Reeves landing on mud flats in 1938.](http://youtube.com/watch?v=zpK6Q_sdJMw)

While most of use know the rating as a *"Float Rating"*, the FAA officially designates the privilege as a ["Seaplane Rating"](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/seaplane_handbook/media/faa-h-8083-23-2.pdf). Therefore the aircraft must be in a *"seaplane"* configuration in-order to require a special license.

Amazingly, the FAA does not require a sign-off or special training for skis - despite the fact there can be as much or more of a difference in technique compared to the mandatory tail wheel sign-off!

Answer (score 0):

The original useful purpose for skimming was to allow landing by bush planes in tight areas near water. This is what is meant by skimming:

[image]

[Youtube](https://youtu.be/Q0fByofsZvo?t=50)

and there are no specific regulations against doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Like a lot of things where there are no legal prohibitions, the real issue is if you have in-motion hull insurance or not.  If you don't have in-motion hull, knock yourself out.  If you do, better make sure its covered, otherwise you'll be in for a surprise if you mess up.

Comment: Most insurance companies I have dealt with won't even cover insurance for an accident on a dirt strip; it has to be an "improved" runway i.e. paved and lighted.